# how to reflect changes in the database without running the app again?

Tags: iphone, sqlite, uipickerview

I am(new to iPhone) developing an iPhone App which tracks the data Usage(wifi,cellular). I am giving an option to the user to add new plans which will be put into a table in the database(sqlite).
I am displaying the list of plans in a picker view and I want to refresh the data in the picker view as soon as user enters a new plan. As of now pickerview is getting updated in the next run :(
thanks in advance.
code is here:

```
    actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [actionSheet setActionSheetStyle:UIActionSheetStyleBlackTranslucent];
    CGRect pickerFrame = CGRectMake(0, 40, 0, 0);
    pickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:pickerFrame];
    pickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
    pickerView.dataSource = self;
    pickerView.delegate = self;
    [actionSheet addSubview:pickerView];
    plans= [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSLog(@"Data base is entering");
    NSString *path1  = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"antara" ofType:@"sqlite"];
    FMDatabase *db1  = [[FMDatabase alloc] initWithPath:path1];
    [db1 open];
    FMResultSet *fResult2= [db1 executeQuery:@"SELECT * FROM main"];
    NSLog(@"fresult2 ready"); 
    while ( [fResult2 next])
    {
        planData = [fResult2 stringForColumn:@"planName"];
        [plans addObject:planData];
        NSLog(@"The data is =%@",planData);
    }
    [db1 close];
    [pickerView selectRow:1 inComponent:0 animated:NO];
    //mlabel.text= [plans objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]];
    //[self setCurrentPlan:[plans objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]]];
    //[mlabel setText:[self getCurrentPlan]];
    currentPlan= [plans objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]];
    [plan setText:currentPlan];
    [pickerView release];
```

Comment: Please paste your code where you have written datasource function for picker.

Comment: @rahul: I've added the code in the question

Comment: OK, your code looks fine. Question is when is the data inserted into the db? If the data is inserted into the db when the pickerview is not currently displaying then this should have worked fine. But looking at your problem description it seems like you want to reload the data even when the picker view is displaying. Is this assumption correct?

Comment: exactly!! I want to reload the data even when the picker view is displaying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need some separation in your code. Try this and tell me if it works

1) Take out the logic of pulling data from DB into a separate function, lets call it loadPlans.

```
- (void) loadPlans {
plans= [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSLog(@"Data base is entering");
NSString *path1  = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"antara" ofType:@"sqlite"];
FMDatabase *db1  = [[FMDatabase alloc] initWithPath:path1];
[db1 open];
FMResultSet *fResult2= [db1 executeQuery:@"SELECT * FROM main"];
NSLog(@"fresult2 ready");

while ( [fResult2 next])
{
    planData = [fResult2 stringForColumn:@"planName"];
    [plans addObject:planData];
    NSLog(@"The data is =%@",planData);
}


[db1 close];
}
```

2) Obviously this code is taken from the function you had pasted above and hence, remove these lines from that function.

3) Under normal flow: Call loadPlans before the call to the above mentioned function

4) Whenever you have something inserted in the database. Call these two functions again there

```
[self loadPlans];
[PickerView reloadComponent:n];
```

This all assumes that the db entry of the plan is happening on the same page and in the same thread so that you have control over it, where you can call these functions. If this assumption is not true then also explain how and when the plans are getting added to db, paste some code about db entry too here.

Answer (score 0):

all you need to do is to trigger a rebuilding the components you are showing by

```
[customPickerView reloadComponent:n] // where n = the index of the component
```

put the trigger code somewhere after the loading has finished.

You may also use something like this to check if the pickerView is visible and if you really need to update the screen:

```
 if ([screenUpdateDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(whateverIneedToDo:)]) {
         [screenUpdateDelegate whateverIneedToDo:withParameterIfYouLike];
```